# jupyter matplotlib interactive exit

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have plotted an interactive figure, run the cell, and now all my keyboard presses are being captured by the interactive plot. How do I exist this without the mouse?

Shift-enter sort of works, but it seems to require there be a cell below the plot.

I think matplotlib recommends ctrl-w but as I am in a web browser (Jupyter) that would just close my tab.

The plot is within the cell.

```
%matplotlib notebook

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.random(size=(100, 1))
ax.plot(x, y)
```

If you run this, you can't then use j,k to move up and down cells until you exit the interactive plot.

This is just a code snippet, in the actual code I am updating the plot from within a loop which is why I'm using interactive mode.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't know it was possible to draw outside of the cell, I have updated the question in hopes of making it more clear. Thank you for pointing out the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another short-key to close the plot. This can be accomplished via the `rcParams`.
So let's say you want to close the plot by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["keymap.quit"] = "ctrl+w", "cmd+w", "q" 

plt.plot([1,3,2])
```

Now pressing <kbd>q</kbd> will exit the interactive plot, such that you can navigate as usual through the notebook. E.g. to then get to the next cell, which would already be active, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Eventually you would probably want to change your [matplotlib rc file](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) with this option not to have to type it in every time you start a notebook.

Comment: Thank you, this does work, though I have now realized I didn't ask the question right. I'll leave it as is because I don't want to radically change the meaning of this post. But, what if I didn't want to exit, but wanted instead just regain control of the keyboard? (This can be done with the mouse)

Comment: Mhh, since the matplotlib plot captures all the keybord inputs, it will be hard to keep it active but still return to the jupyter notebook. For the moment I have to admit I have no idea if it is possible or how to even tackle this problem, sorry.